# Iterating through data-* elements using JQuery $.children() and $.each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to iterate through my HTML code and pick every element that harbors the "data-*" attribute and collect it's value. I have looked on the web and only found ways to collect data on specific data-* elements. I need to get the data-* value without knowing the element name, and so I found the .children() jquery method. However I don't know how to implement it all together.

Here's a quick example of what I'm doing:

HTML:

```
<div data-example="master">
    <div data-example="i">
        <div data-example="a">
            <span data-example="1"></span>
        </div>
        <div data-example="b">
            <span data-example="2"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-example="ii">
        <div data-example="c">
            <span data-example="3"></span>
        </div>
        <div data-example="d">
            <span data-example="4"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var master = [];
$("#master").children(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var data = element.data('example');
    master.push(data);
}
```

So for this particular example, I want my end-game to have the master array equal [i, a, 1, b, 2, ii, c, 3, d, 4].

But I'm not doing it right because nothing is happening when I trigger the JQuery event.

Comment: You're using `$("#master")` but you don't have an element with an `id` of "master". Also, `.children` will just give you the 2 divs that are the children ('i' and 'ii'). It doesn't give you all of the descendants. Much easier to do what @Rayon posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Attribute` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and apply [**`Array.prototype.map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over it.

```js
console.log(Array.from($('[data-example]')).map(function(elem) {
  return $(elem).data('example');
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-example="master">
  <div data-example="i">
    <div data-example="a">
      <span data-example="1"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-example="b">
      <span data-example="2"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-example="ii">
    <div data-example="c">
      <span data-example="3"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-example="d">
      <span data-example="4"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```